# How to make multiple APIs in parallel using Python Django?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, api, asynchronous

Currently, I have 2 API enpoints. The first API enpoint takes in a file as input and performs some calculations that take up to 30 minutes. The second API endpoint is a healthcheck that returns the status of the first API. Possible healthchecks are 15% complete, 25% complete, 50% complete, 75% complete, 90% complete and 100% complete. Using Python I want to write code that calls the first API and then every 10 seconds calls the second API and returns the percentage complete. Then I would like to end the healthcheck calls once 100% has been completed. This is all code used in a Django project, where I would like the UI to get updated. Without the healthcheck, the code for that constant update looks something like: `return render(request, 'processing.html', context)`.

The code that I was thinking I could do this with would be something like the one below. That being said, I'm not sure if I'm handling the parallel asynchronous tasks correctly. I was thinking if multiprocessing or threading would be a good approach here but I'm not sure of the exact syntax.

```
import requests
import time

async def first_api(body, api_url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(api_url, data=body) as response:
            return await response.json()

async def health_api(body, api_url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(api_url, data=body) as response:
    health = response.json().get('health')
    return health

def process():
    await first_api()
    while True:
        health = call_second_api()
        # I want to render the updated page if the new health is different than before but that would break the loop so I'm unsure of how to proceed. 
        return render(request, 'processing.html', context)
        if health == 100:
            break
        time.sleep(10)
```

There is a final consideration, that I haven't incorporated that I need to consider. How exactly can I do all of the parallel API calls while continuously rendering the UI with the accurate health value? I'm a bit lost on how to proceed here. In particular, I would like assistance with 1. The proper way how to use asynchronous calls to make these parallel API calls and 2. The proper way to continuously update the webpage with these dynamically changing health values.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

These are API endpoints, not API's, which simplifies the question.

If you want to schedule code execution or do any kind of parallel processing with Django you should be integrating Celery to do this. Django views only really exist to handle things "in series" and traditionally call out to a task queue like Celery to handle the parallel processing.

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Alternatively, since the goal is to update a UI based on the status of a health check call, you could simplify this to one API that uses web sockets to do a server to client push as the health check updates. I've always manually handled web socket integration but Django Channels now exists as a better way to do this:
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will go through the Celery documentation, but would that resolve the issue with updating the UI? I don't want to schedule the code execution. I want to do it based on a user's file submission on the website.

Comment: For the UI updating I'd really recommend using websockets here through Channels. A longstanding backend process that a user needs to keep tabs on is the perfect use case for websocket integration.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to using Django Channels so I might have some follow-up questions, but I'll be sure to go through the documentation!